# Conditional return to beginning of function

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to return or repeat the function if the results of it do not meet the criteria. I've tried various things, such as `do while` statements, settings a `BOOL` flag, etc. and have been unsuccessful. What's the best way to restart the function until the criteria is met?

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main() {
        std:int nine;
        std::srand(std::time(NULL));
        std::cout << nine << (rand() % 10);
        std::cout << '\n';
    if (nine == 9) {
        std::cout << 'nine';
    } else {
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use `main` for recursion? just define another recursive function and use it inside of `main`. it might be done by iteration tho

Comment: @mangusta, good question - but i thought it would work, and that's why i'm asking. do you have an example perhaps? thx

Comment: g++: warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function ‘::main’ [-pedantic]

Comment: "int" is a keyword; it isn't defined in any namespace. Also, I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but I can't see how a loop couldn't help you achieve it. Recursion is typically a bad idea if you don't know for sure the upper limit for the recursion depth will be reasonable.

Comment: @heinrichj, I wanted to reach beyond what was recursionally possible, well, maybe not. thanks for the explanation - sorry my example apparently was quite poor, but hopefully you can get the idea of what i meant.

Comment: In this case (fortuitously), `goto std;` has the same effect as `main();` :-) But there are too many other problems that need fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not recursively call main in C++. Also your code contains some other errors. The program could look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
        std::srand( ( unsigned )std::time( NULL) );
        int nine;

        do
        {      
                nine = std::rand() % 10;
        } while ( nine != 9 );

        std::cout << "nine" << std::endl;
}
```

You could also add an output statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
        std::srand( ( unsigned )std::time( NULL) );
        int nine;

        do
        {      
                nine = std::rand() % 10;
                std::cout << nine << std::endl;
        } while ( nine != 9 );

        std::cout << "nine" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A while loop should work just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int nine = 0;
    srand(std::time(NULL));

    while (nine != 9)
    {
      nine = (rand() % 10);
      std::cout << nine << std::endl;

      if (nine == 9) {
        std::cout << 'nine';
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is in `nine` , you don't assign it

```
nine = rand()%10;
```

and with the basic loop it should be fine

```
while ( nine != 9){
      nine = rand()%10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int main() {

     std::srand(std::time(NULL));

     do {
          std:int nine;
          std::cout << nine << (rand() % 10);
          std::cout << '\n';
          if(nine == 9) {
              std::cout << 'nine';
              break;
          } 
     } while(true);
}
```

Note that you don't ever change `nine` in your code, the loop will go forever.

Answer (score 0):

This particular code wouldn't even compile due to the `std:int` (missing colon typo).  But assuming the typo was fixed, it also wouldn't do anything because you never assign a value to `nine`.

Anyway, if you want to repeat an action in your code, your best bet is a loop:

```
int nine = 0;
do {
  nine = rand() % 10;
} while (nine != 9);
```

Comment: really? it worked for me. maybe loosen up your compiler chassis a bit. yes, it was a mistake, so thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Sure it compiles -- `std` is just a label! See my comment to the OP.